# How to become a expert in Flight Operations Business? (Flight Dispatch, Weight and Balance etc.. )

Tags: flight-training, flight-planning, iata

I am working in IT industry relavent to airline operations (like flight dispatch related products).I would like to enhance my knowledge in Flight operations area.

What are the trainings (IATA/others) or courses  recommended for flight operations related business process?

Comment: A starting point insofar as weight and balance is concerned, would be to become thoroughly familiar with the FAA's Advisory Circular AC 120-27. You can pick up a PDF of it at https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC120-27E.pdf. As I remember, it doesn't cover computerized systems, but it's still good for a basic introduction. Weight and balance complexity can run from the very simple to the very complex depending on the aircraft and usage. If you want to play with an online w&b program, you can do so at wb.terryliittschwager.com.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you are located and what country you are located in as to what kind of license will be beneficial to you. If you are in the United States, obtaining a FAA dispatch license is a common route to working in flight operations. There are community college programs to prepare you to take the exams. The benefit to the FAA license is it never expires. In other countries there are similar licenses you can obtain. I would be cautious to IATA programs mainly due to the price and many are geared towards existing professionals in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a little lengthy, but taking a course to get a Dispatcher license would cover a wide range of those topics in depth.

One example from Jeppesen: [here](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/industry-solutions/aviation/commercial/training/ground-flight-ops-level-2.jsp).

A Google search for **course dispatcher license** will give you other options.

Comment: Thank you for sharing information.  How about iata airline operations diploma..  Will that be good?